# creation of CREDITS errored: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":291279815469,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params"

Tags: erc20

Error in code I built yesterday

I'm using remix -> METAMASK Ropsten testnet

pragma solidity  >=0.4.19

Error content:

> creation of CREDITS pending...
> creation of CREDITS errored: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload
> {"id":291279815469,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["..."],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object]

Can you help me with this?

Comment: pragma solidity  >=0.4.19<0.6.0;

contract Ownable {
    address public owner;
    function Ownable() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurred again today :(

Reinstall "metamask" deletion
I think it's an interlocking error. :)

Try to work after the

Delete "metaMASK" -> Reinstall -> Log in to "metamask" ->Restart "remix"->
Interlink check -> deploy

Answer (score 0):

self-addressed
Log out of "MetaMask" after deleting cache from setup
Reboot your computer later.

I succeeded like this.

But I don't know why I'm so successful.. :(